# Magento 1.9.2.1 overloads Percona 5.7: Waiting for table metadata lock on cataloginventory_stock_status

Tags: magento-1.9, database, performance

I'm working on a Magento 1.9.2.1 shop where we have some stability issue. From time to time, the Percona 5.7 database hits the "too many connections" limit and the shop becomes unresponsive. `SHOW processlist` seems to reveal that the issue is caused by a lot of query stuck `Waiting for table metadata lock` on this query: `SELECT cataloginventory_stock_status.product_id, cataloginventory_stock_status.stock_status`.

The server has active visitors, but it's by no mean under heavy load.

`max_connection` is set to 1024 (verified via `show variables like '%connections%';`)

[This is the full output of processlist](https://pastebin.com/Vmr8g5ZZ)

Any hint is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid lock, you should use *READ COMMITTED* transaction isolation level.

It's seems that you are importing stocks and reindexing data in the same time, you can also change scheduling.

I can tell you that with this request :

```
ALTER TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status` DISABLE KEYS
```

You can check this [Github issue](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/152) for answer

Comment: Will try read committed, thanks. Could you please what male you think that import stock an reindex are running at The same time?

Comment: Check edited answer